# htmlentities() не заменяет, а удаляет двойные кавычки в html тегах

Tags: php, html, преобразование

Перед добавлением записи в базу данных, пользуюсь в PHP коде преобразованием текста с помощью `htmlentities()`.

В тексте имеются html теги (например `<img src="url_image" alt="alt_text">`), в тегах есть атрибуты с двойными кавычками (например `src="url_image"`).

В PHP коде использую функцию `htmlentities()` следующим образом: `$text = htmlentities($_POST["text"], ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8");`.

Все символы преобразуются в html сущности правильно, но двойные кавычки вообще удаляются из атрибутов. То есть `"` должно меняться на `&quot;`, но вместо этого `"` просто удаляется.

В результате возникают трудности с дальнейшим выводом текста на сайте.

Если кто-то сможет помочь, буду благодарен! Спасибо!

Comment: здесь все хорошо http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ecd13cc0c859ed2e2ae7b3a468a79dff8eecdfa8

Comment: Действительно, странно! А из за чего может у меня на сайте не работать? Из-за настроек сервера может быть?

Comment: в другом месте удаляешь, до или после этой функции, для этого ставят дебаггер.

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь, но я ничего не понял.

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/250323/ или https://mbaev.com/posts/otladka-php-c-xdebug-v-php-storm.html

Answer (score -1):

Проблема решена. Дело было в том, что был подключен файл защиты от SQL инъекций, который автоматически везде убирал кавычки. Всем спасибо.